# Did opposition fundraising stop neonazis marching?

Tags: politics, germany, nazi-germany

From [Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ij2W.jpg):

> "In the small town in Germany where the Nazi leader Rudolf Hess was born, every year right wing activist[s] have been showing up to commemorate his birthday. Counter marches didn't stop them. What really got to them was when people organized to sponsor donations on their behalf, treating their march like an AIDS walk.  For every meter marched, there would be 10€ donated to anti-racist organizations. People then turned it into kind of a sports event as they showed up with banners and music cheering the fascists on like 'thank you for marching for racial justice' and updating with bullhorns how much money the fascists marching had already raised." – Yannik Thiem

Did fundraising for anti-nazi groups stop neo-nazis from marching in Hess's town?

A quick google search came up with news about the fundraising, but not about the annual marches stopping.

Comment: [Rudolf Hess was born in Alexandria, Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolf_Hess) At that time, the family had a summer home in Reicholdsgrün (now part of Kirchenlamitz). Young Hess attended a boarding school in Bad Godesberg, then a school in Neuchâtel, Switzerland, then went to Hamburg.

Comment: @JanDoggen: Hess's parents lived in the town of Wunsiedel, and were also buried there. Even though he never lived in that town, Hess wanted to be buried next to his parents after his death, which was what happened in 1987. He was exhumed in 2011 and buried at sea in order to stop the neo-nazi marches.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Who claims that the fundraiser (which was an actual event, and which continue to be held in order to react to neo-nazi marches) stopped these types of marches? The facebook post doesn't make this claim, does it?

Comment: @Schmuddi, *"Counter marches didn't stop them. What really got to them was when..."* implies that the fundraiser did the trick. That's how I (and presumably Andrew Grimm) read it.

Comment: @Jordy: Fair enough, I'm not a native speaker. I always understood the meaning of the expression *to get to s.o.* to be something like "to unsettle s.o.".

Comment: @Schmuddi "Get to" means exactly that, yes. But the way it's written suggests that it unsettled the nazis so much that they stopped marching. It strongly suggests something along the lines of "Counter-protests didn't stop them, but this crazy trick did." (Please excuse the clickbait-ese.)

Comment: [A 2014 version in the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/nov/18/neo-nazis-tricked-into-raising-10000-for-charity) does not have the implicit claim *What really got to them was when*.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**No**.

This question is probably about the successor marches to the infamous "[Rudolf-Heß-Gedächtnismarsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolf-He%C3%9F-Gedenkmarsch)" which had mainly been taking place in [Wunsiedel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wunsiedel), where Rudolf Heß had been *buried* until 2011, as well as about the internationally recognized, fundraising counter protest "[Rechts gegen Rechts](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechts_gegen_Rechts)" which premiered in Wunsiedel in 2014.

I could find reports about Nazis marching in Wunsiedel for every year since the "Rechts gegen Rechts" campaign started in 2014:

- 2014: [200 Nazis.](https://www.endstation-rechts-bayern.de/2014/11/aus-neonazi-heldengedenken-wird-wunsiedler-spendenlauf/)
- 2015: [230 Nazis, 500 counter protesters](https://www.endstation-rechts-bayern.de/2015/11/gespenstischer-fackelmarsch-durchs-nasskalte-wunsiedel/).
- 2016: [200 Nazis, 400 counter protesters](http://www.br.de/nachrichten/oberfranken/inhalt/wunsiedel-ist-bunt-neonazis-100.html).
- (2017: Nazi rally planned in Berlin in November, 500 attendees expected. ([Source](https://www.bnr.de/artikel/aktuelle-meldungen/braunes-gedenken-in-berlin-geplant) as per Wikipedia))

The fundraising counter protest does not appear to have had an effect on the raw number of attendees, let alone did the marches stop. However, one source mentioned that the composition of the attendees had apparently changed from predominantly local Nazis to Nazis "imported" from other federal states.